# What is meant by "expand f[x,y]=xy in powers of x-1 and y-1"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question refers to C.H. Edwards, Jr.'s Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, Chapter II-7, Example 2.

> Suppose we want to expand $f[x,y]=xy$ in powers of $x-1$ and $y-1$.  Of course the result will be
>
> $xy=1+(x-1)+(y-1)+(x-1)(y-1)$,
>
> but let us obtain this result by calculating the second degree Taylor polynomial $P_2[\mathbf{h}]$ of $f[x,y]$ at $\mathbf{a}=\{1,1\}$ with $\mathbf{h}=\{h_1,h_2\}=\{x-1,y-1\}$. ...

Establishing the equivalence is a matter of simple algebra, but "expand $f[x,y]=xy$ in powers of $x-1$ and $y-1$" has no clear meaning to me.  Edwards obviously does not mean to use a Taylor polynomial, because he wants to show the above result is equivalent to the Taylor polynomial.

What exactly does it mean to expand a function in powers of some given pattern?  I'm assuming this is something I should have learned in high school.

Comment: probably like a multivariable taylor expansion around $x=1,y=1$

Comment: I added more text from the example to make it clear that the Taylor polynomial is not what was meant.  The objective is to show the result to be the same as the Taylor expansion.

Comment: You can make many polynomial approximations which are not Taylor polynomials, unless a more clear description of how to obtain the coefficients it's difficult to prove them to be the same.

Comment: @mathreadler That's why I asked the question.  Edwards obviously expects the reader to know what is meant by 'expand f in powers of ...'.  But I would not have had a clue what was meant had he not shown the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$To *expand a polynomial $p(x, y)$ in powers of $x - a$ and $y - b$* is to find coefficients $c_{jk}$ (which turn out to exist uniquely, and with all but finitely many equal to $0$) such that
$$
p(x, y) = \sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty} c_{j,k} (x - a)^{j} (y - b)^{k}.
$$
(If the total degree of $p$ is $N$, the sum is limited to indices with $j + k \leq N$.)

One way to achieve this expansion is to write, using your example $p(x, y) = xy$,
\begin{align*}
  xy &= \bigl(a + (x - a)\bigr) \bigl(b + (y - b)\bigr) \\
  &= ab + b(x - a) + a(y - b) + (x - a)(y - b).
  \tag{1}
\end{align*}
(Analogous use of the binomial theorem handles arbitrary monomials $x^{\ell} y^{m}$, and every polynomial in two variables is a finite sum of monomials.)

Another way approach is to invoke Taylor's theorem:
$$
p(x, y) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{\dd^{n} p}{\dd^{j} x\, \dd^{n-j} y}(a, b)\, \frac{(x - a)^{j}}{j!}\, \frac{(y - b)^{n-j}}{(n - j)!}.
\tag{2}
$$
Again taking $p(x, y) = xy$, one finds
$$
c_{0,0} = p(a, b) = ab,\quad
c_{1,0} = \frac{\dd p}{\dd x}(a, b) = b,\quad
c_{0,1} = \frac{\dd p}{\dd y}(a, b) = a,\quad
c_{1,1} = \frac{\dd^{2} p}{\dd x\, \dd y}(a, b) = 1,
$$
with all other partial derivatives vanishing, so that (2) agrees with (1). This is presumably the content of Edwards' example.

Generally, (2) yields the coefficients
$$
c_{j,k} = \frac{\dd^{j+k} p}{\dd^{j} x\, \dd^{k} y}(a, b)\, \frac{1}{j!\, k!}.
$$

There are similar formulas for sufficiently smooth (non-polynomial) functions, perhaps with infinitely many non-zero coefficients, and with "error" or "remainder" terms.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $x$ as $(x-1)+1$ and similarly for $y=(y-1)+1$. Now let $X=x-1$ and $Y=y-1$. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y)=xy&=&((x-1)+1)((y-1)+1)=(X+1)(Y+1) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=&XY&+&X&+&Y&+&1 \\
&=&(x-1)(y-1)&+&(x-1)&+&(y-1)&+&1
\end{eqnarray*}
So the solution you give in the question is spot on.